# Extract date from a website page

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I need to extract date from a page, for example:

```
<div class="update" style="width: 1037px;">
    Last update:
    <span id="last_update">6.30.2011</span>
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the date (6.30.2011, in the above example).
I have jsoup: Java HTML Parser.

Comment: I’ve formatted your code. Take care to indent every code by four spaces (or, more easily, by selecting it and pressing the “Code Sample” button above the input box, or use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 2):

Using jSoup it’s as easy as

```
Element result = doc.select("#last_update").first();
String date = result.text();
```

Comment: That said, it’s unusual to have IDs with underscore in them since that’s not a valid CSS identifier. Usually you should use a hyphen instead.

Comment: @Gareth Thanks, never knew. Somehow the hyphen got established though.

Comment: I think it's totally preference. I always use underscores.

Comment: @Ron then your code doesn’t correspond to what you’ve shown us – this code definitely works.